# set cookie in WebSocket only if missing

Tags: node.js, cookies, websocket

We can set the cookie in WebSocket handshake: [Set cookie inside websocket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191517/set-cookie-inside-websocket-connection), however I can't decide whether the cookie was already set:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8088 });

wss.on("headers", onHeaders);

function onHeaders(headers) {
    console.log("onHeaders cookie: " + headers.cookie); // undefined
    headers.push('Set-Cookie: ' + cookie.serialize('client', 1));
}
```

How can I see whether the "client" value is already available, before setting the cookie?

Answer (score 1):

Install a handler function for the `connection` event on the WebSocket server.  This fires when a WebSocket request is received, and it is passed a `request` object (an instance of `http.IncomingMesssage`) as an argument.  You can examine the headers of the `request` object to see whether your cookie is present in the request.  Something like:

```
wss.on('connection', onConnection);

function onConnection(websock, request) {
    console.log(request.headers);
}
```

although of course you'll want to do something more complicated than just printing the headers.

Comment: We can examine cookies when connection event is received, but we cannot update/add cookies at this point.